# Який термін можна використовувати замість "начертальна" геометрія?

Tags: терміни, вживання-слів, росіянізм

Є такий [підручник](http://www.library.univ.kiev.ua/ukr/elcat/new/detail.php3?doc_id=716597): Чалий О.Т. **«Начертальна геометрія»**, К., М. 1952

[image: Підручник «Начертальна геометрія»]

Слово *«начертальна»* у його назві мені здається русизмом.

СУМ також [містить](http://google.sum.in.ua/s/nachertaljna_gheometrija) еквівалент *нарисна геометрія*, але він мені також здається русизмом, разом із *«рисувати»*.

Чи існує усталений термін, який використовується замість цього слова?
Я також буду радий відповідям, які могли б аргументовано довести, що *«начертальний»* є правильним словом у цьому контексті.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`Нарисна` мені здається досить вдалим словом.

- [`Рисунок`](http://sum.in.ua/s/rysunok) потрапляє посеред *формально-схематичним* [`кресленням`](http://sum.in.ua/s/kreslennja) і *художнім* [`малюнком`](http://sum.in.ua/s/maljunok)
- є *питоме* слово [`риса`](http://sum.in.ua/s/rysa) у значенні:

> Лінія, проведена на чому-небудь.

- Нарисна геометрія це розділ геометрії

> що вивчає методи зображення тривимірних об'єктів, використовуючи двовимірні проекції

Тобто **нарисна геометрія** вивчає перетворення (проекцію) тривимірних об'єктів у лінії, проведені на площині, тобто риси, з яких складається зображення тривимірного об'єкту - **рисунок**

Comment: «Нарисова» також була б чудовим словом. Як ви вважаєте?

Comment: Ні, не була б. Бо тоді та геометрія наче буде мати [справу з нарисами](http://sum.in.ua/s/narysovyj). Порівняйте `розумний`(той хто має змогу вміло своїм розумом користуватися) - `розумовий`(той що має відношення до розуму), `сильний` (той хто має змогу використати силу) - `силовий` (той хто має відношення до сили). та геометрія вона ті риски використовує, але вивчає методи проекції. Тобто геометрія все ж нарисна, проекційна

Comment: Може, звісно, `нарискова` геометрія - та що має стосунок до, вивчає проекції (на-) рисок. Але тоді суто вивчає, а не має за питому і вирізняючу серед інишх геометрій частину методу

Answer (score 1):

В університеті в нас був предмет "Нарисна геометрія" (НТУУ "КПІ"), тому думаю, що цей варіант правильний
Ось посилання на наші підручники:
 1. Хмеленко О.С. Нарисна геометрія;
 2. Нарисна геометрія. Інженерна та комп’ютерна графіка - Василий
    Макаров, Валентина Шевченко.

Comment: -1: Це словосполучення міститься у запитанні, і автор пояснює, чим са́ме воно йому не подобається. Окремо від того, наявність якогось предмету у деякому виші не означає автоматично, що це словосполучення — найкращий вибір.

Comment: Дякую за відповідь. Але у відповідях ми надаємо перевагу інформацію, яку можна перевірити. Чи могли б Ви якось підтвердити Вашу інформацію? Наприклад, дати посилання на підручник/посібник, що використовувався у Вашому університеті і містить таке словосполучення. Хоч скажіть, який у Вас університет?

Comment: 1. Хмеленко О.С. Нарисна геометрія
2. Нарисна геометрія. Інженерна та комп’ютерна графіка -  Василий Макаров, Валентина Шевченко

Університет - НТУУ "КПІ"

Comment: @bytebuster, а Ви, до речі нічого не питаєте про те, росіянізми це чи ні. Ви питаєте: «Який термін можна використовувати? Чи є усталений термін?» («Здається» росіянізмом — це взагалі не аргумент; і про «найкращу» в питанні нічого немає.) Отже відповідь формально цілком відповідає. (Це вже Ви не зовсім точно сформулювати запитання, а не Marina не змогла вгадати.)